# How to hide ion-slides pager?

Tags: ionic-framework

I use the `ion-slide` directive documented [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/slides/Slides/) and I cannot find a method to hide the pager. I tried setting the pager attribute as in:

```
<ion-slides options="myOptions" pager="false" slider="mySlide[item.id]">
```

however that does not work, the pager bullets are still showing.

Is it possible to hide the ion-slides pager, and if so - how?

Answer (score 24):

official solution:

```
options="{pagination: false}"
```

Comment: @Andy can you post a link to the page which offers this solution? I only know of http://www.idangero.us/swiper/api/#.VsiaPpN95E4 According to that page, pagination needs to be set to "String with CSS selector or HTML element of the container with pagination". It does not specify that `false` is a valid option for that field

Comment: unfortunally, i didn't find this solution. A user in Ionic forum answered me 2 days ago. Here the post: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/hide-pages-in-the-new-ion-slides-component/43893

Comment: To add to this answer, if you're setting options outside of the template, you need to pass this options object into the `<ion-slides>` directive by assigning it to your scope, such as `scope.options = {pagination: false}`, and then `<ion-slides options="options">`

Comment: This is the correct answer....but how come the documention for ionSlides is not up to date with the options API and the correct delegate  ? http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlides/

Answer (score 4):

Just add this in your `css`:

```
.swiper-pagination-bullet{
   background:white!important;
   border-radius: 100%;
   height: 17px;   
   width: 17px;
   display: none;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `pager`.

Example:

```
<ion-slides pager loop autoplay="1500" class="auto_height"> ...
```

just put (without "pager"):

```
<ion-slides loop autoplay="1500" class="auto_height"> ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If these slides are being added to an [ion-slide-box](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlideBox/), you can:

```
show-pager="false"
```

on the `ion-slide-box`.  See the docs for more info.

You might also be able to hide them via css like:

```
.slider-pager { display:none; }
```

Comment: 1. The project is using `ion-slides` (for performance reasons, I think). Is it interchangeable with ion-slide-box?

Comment: 2. The `display:none` approach works, though it's a bit hack-ish. I was hoping to find the official method. Does it not exist?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the library.  From the docs, could you just remove the `pager` from your line altogether?

Answer (score 0):

i'm searching a solution for this question. I'm workig on this since 2 days.. But nothing. Do you resolve this problem? I added .slider-pager { display:none; } but the dots still remain!

Comment: I didn't resolve the problem, but was able to  workaround it using this CSS:
`.swiper-pagination.swiper-pagination-clickable {
  display: none;
}`

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do like this;

```
paginationType: 'custom',
paginationBulletRender: function (index, className) {
     return '';
}
```

This is better than `pagination:false`